# prepareForSegue and MVC design

Tags: objective-c, model-view-controller, uitableview, segue

I have a basic table view controller that displays model object data, let's call that object `userInfo`. Each cell segues to a different view controller where the user can modify `userInfo` properties. One property is an array `names`. Each `name` in the array is displayed in single table section. The name cell segues to a simple view controller with a textfield to edit the `name` or add a `name` to the array.

This a very simple concept, but I see a few different ways of implementing. I'd like to use the cleanest approach that conforms best to MVC design.

In my current implementation prepareForSegue

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"EditName"]) {
        EditNameVC *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.userInfo = self.userInfo;
        NSArray *names = [self.userInfo objectForKey:@"names"];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSDictionary *nameInfo = [names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *name = [nameInfo objectForKey:@"title"];
        if (name) {
            controller.name = name;
        }
    }
```

I pass an `isEditing` BOOL to tell EditNameVc that a `nameInfo` dictionary will be replaced rather than added to the `array`. This presents an issue in the destination view controller. If editing a `name`, how will the vc know what index to replace the dictionary at? Should I create a private property in EditNameVC `oldNameObject`, loop through each `nameInfo` ins `names` and use `replaceObjectIdenticalTo`? Should I pass indexPath? Either option seems sloppy.

As another consideration, should EditTableVC know nothing about a model object and just call a delegate to the main table view controller which then modifies the model object?

Comment: I like the delegate option the best.  Keeping your VC's as loosely coupled as possible is usually the best practice.

Comment: So if I were to call a delegate method, `EditTableVCDidFinishEditing`, would I pass the new string as a paramater and then set the returned string to my model object in my main table vc?

Comment: Not related to your question exactly but since you're interested in structure....  IMO, your `prepareForSegue:` is dealing with a lot of information that it doesn't need.  If `EditNameVC` had a method that gave it the `userInfo` and an offset, it could take responsibility for finding its own name.

Comment: For something this simple I think delegates add a lot of bulk, I would probably use a block completion handler. It's the same idea but you don't have to declare a protocol etc

Comment: @Paul.s Do you have an example? I know what blocks are, but I'm curios as to how to use one in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

To do this with a block completion you would need to do...

In the editing viewController (the one you push on) you would need to the declaration for a block pointer

```
@interface YourClass : UIViewController

// some properties
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^onCompletion)(NSString *editedName);

@end
```

Then in the implementation you need to cal this block when your done action is called:

```
- (void)doneTapped;
{
  if (self.onCompletion) {
    self.onCompletion(self.editedName);    
  }
}
```

Now all you need to do is set up the call back where you push this controller on

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"EditName"]) {
  // Create and set up controller

  controller.onCompletion = ^(NSString *editedString) {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    // do whatever you want with the edited string
    // If names was mutable

    [names replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:editedString];
  }
}
```

I've tried to stick to similar names but you would most likely generalise this more